# What are RVP signs?

Tags: airport, uk

I never saw these in the US, but certainly at UK airports and airfields you will often see "RVP" on a green background with a yellow border:

[image: RVP Sign]
<sub>Source: http://www.sabre-roads.org.uk/gallery/displayimage.php?pos=-4476</sub>

What is the purpose of these signs, and who/what is their intended audience?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a Rendezvous Point for emergency vehicles. This is from the UK's *[Aerodrome Model Emergency Orders](http://www.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP576.pdf)* (appendix B, section 1.1.1):

> Rendezvous Point signs should be displayed at the point(s) designated
>   by the Aerodrome Emergency Orders as the rendezvous point(s) for all
>   responding Emergency Services. Signs should be clearly visible from
>   any direction from which responding Emergency Service vehicles/
>   personnel are likely to approach when attending aircraft
>   accidents/incidents within the response area defined by or cross-
>   referenced in the Aerodrome Manual.